# android viewflow swipe images from sdcard

Tags: android, adapter, swipe-gesture

I'm working on a project which is saving some images to sdcard and now I have to create viewflow to show this images. I'm getting the images by it's Id from sdCard and my problem now is how to swipe between different images. Here is the code I'm using :

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageButton;

public class Cards extends Activity {

    public Cursor cursor;
    int position;
    int indexxx;
    Bitmap b;
    int objectId;
    int cardsId;

    private ViewFlow viewFlow;
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.circle_layout); 
        UserDatabaseHelper userDbHelper = new UserDatabaseHelper(this, null, 1);
        userDbHelper.initialize(this);


        final int cardId = getIntent().getIntExtra("card_id",0);
        Log.i("Card Id ","Card Id : "+cardId);
        final int collId = getIntent().getIntExtra("collection_id",0);
        Log.i("Collection Id ","Collection Id : "+collId);

        position = getIntent().getIntExtra("position",0);
        Log.i("position","position : "+position);

        String cardSQL = "SELECT cm.objectId "+
         "FROM cardmedias AS cm "+
         "INNER JOIN cards AS cd "+
         "ON (cm.cardId = cd.objectId) "+
         "WHERE cd.collectionId="+collId;

        Cursor cards = userDbHelper.executeSQLQuery(cardSQL);
        if (cards.getCount() == 0) {
            Log.i("", "No Image file");
            cards.close();
        } else if (cards.getCount() > 0) {
            for (cards.move(0); cards.moveToNext(); cards.isAfterLast()) {
                cardsId = Integer.parseInt(cards.getString(cards
                        .getColumnIndex("objectId")));
                Log.i("", "cards objectId : " + cardsId);

                String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                        + "/.Stampii/MediaCard/" + cardsId + ".png";
                Log.i("", "path : " + path);
            }
        }

        String sql = "SELECT objectId FROM cardmedias WHERE cardId=" + cardId
                + " LIMIT 1";
        Cursor cursor = userDbHelper.executeSQLQuery(sql);
        if (cursor.getCount() == 0) {
            Log.i("", "No Image file");
            cursor.close();
        } else if (cursor.getCount() > 0) {
            for (cursor.move(0); cursor.moveToNext(); cursor.isAfterLast()) {
                objectId = Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(cursor
                        .getColumnIndex("objectId")));
                Log.i("", "objectId : " + objectId);
            }
        }



        Button info = (Button) findViewById(R.id.info_button);
        info.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Cards.this, SingleCardInfo.class);
                intent.putExtra("card_id", cardId);
                intent.putExtra("collection_id", collId);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        Button back = (Button) findViewById(R.id.back_button);
        back.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                finish();
            }
        });

        final ArrayList<Bitmap> images = new ArrayList<Bitmap>();
        String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/.Stampii/MediaCard/"+objectId+".png";

        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inTempStorage = new byte[16*1024];

        Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, options);
        images.add(b);

        viewFlow = (ViewFlow) findViewById(R.id.viewflow);
        viewFlow.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this, images),position);


        ImageButton prevBtn = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.previous_button);
        prevBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                indexxx = viewFlow.getSelectedItemPosition()-1;
                if (indexxx>=0) {
                    viewFlow.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(Cards.this, images),indexxx);
                    viewFlow.setSelectedItemPosition(indexxx);
                    Log.i("indexxx", "indexxx : " + indexxx);
                }
            }
        });

        ImageButton nextBtn = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.next_button);
        nextBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                indexxx = viewFlow.getSelectedItemPosition()+1;
                if (indexxx<=images.size()) {
                    viewFlow.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(Cards.this, images),indexxx);
                    viewFlow.setSelectedItemPosition(indexxx);
                    Log.i("indexxx", "indexxx : " + indexxx);
                }
            }
        }); 

    }
    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        viewFlow.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }

}
```

And here is my ImageAdapter class :

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    private ArrayList<Bitmap> ids = new ArrayList<Bitmap>();
    private Bitmap bitmap;

    public ImageAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Bitmap> images) {
        mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        ids = images;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 1;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.image_item, null);
        }
        ((ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imgView)).setImageBitmap(ids.get(position));
        return convertView;
    }

}
```

Any idea how can I set the next or previous image by getting it's ID from database, finding the image with that name and adding it in viewflow and swipe. I don't want someone to write the code instead of me... I'm stuck on the idea how can I do this... So if someone can help me with suggestions, ideas or something else just shoot it.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I solve this issue :

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

import com.stampii.stampii.R;
import com.stampii.stampii.comm.rpc.UserDatabaseHelper;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageButton;

public class Cards extends Activity {

    public Cursor cursor;
    int indexxx;
    Bitmap b;
    int objectId;
    int cardsId;
    ArrayList<Integer> ids;
    String path;
    int mediaType = 5001;
    ArrayList<String> images;
    int card;
    String cardSQL;

    private ViewFlow viewFlow;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.circle_layout);
        UserDatabaseHelper userDbHelper = new UserDatabaseHelper(this, null, 1);
        userDbHelper.initialize(this);
        HashMap<Integer, String> hm = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
        ids = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        images = new ArrayList<String>();

        /*
         * Card ID - Getting the right card
         */
        final int cardId = getIntent().getIntExtra("card_id", 0);
        Log.i("Card Id ", "Card Id CARDS : " + cardId);

        /*
         * Collection ID - Getting the right Collection Cards
         */
        final int collId = getIntent().getIntExtra("collection_id", 0);
        Log.i("Collection Id ", "Collection Id : " + collId);

        // Position of Clicked Item
        int position = getIntent().getIntExtra("position", 0);
        Log.i("position", "position : " + position);

        /*
         * Indicating which activity is opening this one for selecting the right
         * cards from Database. Value 1 : All Stampii - listing all owned
         * stampii cards Value 2 : Owned Stampii - listing all owned stampii
         * cards Value 3 : Repeated Stampii - listing only repeated stampii
         * cards Value 4 : Last Acquired - listing the last acquired stampii
         * cards
         */
        int activity = getIntent().getIntExtra("activity", 1);
        Log.d("", "activity : " + activity);

        /*
         * Indicating the Sort Type : Value 1 : Sort by Tags Value 2 : Sort by
         * Categories Value 3 : Sort by Date
         * By Default the sort type is by Tags! (Bad-Ass Muthaphucka)
         */
        int sort = getIntent().getIntExtra("sort_type", 1);
        Log.d("", "sort type : " + sort);

        int extra = getIntent().getIntExtra("extra", 0);
        Log.d("", "extra : " + extra);

        switch (activity) {
        case 1: // All Stampii
                cardSQL = getOwnedCards(sort, collId, extra);
            break;
        case 2: // Owned Stampii
                cardSQL = getOwnedCards(sort, collId, extra);
            break;
        case 3: // Repeated Stampii
                cardSQL = getRepeatedCards(sort, collId, extra);
            break;
        case 4: // Last Acquired
                cardSQL = getOwnedCards(sort, collId, extra);
            break;
        }

        Cursor cards = userDbHelper.executeSQLQuery(cardSQL);
        if (cards.getCount() == 0) {
            cards.close();
        } else if (cards.getCount() > 0) {
            for (cards.move(0); cards.moveToNext(); cards.isAfterLast()) {
                cardsId = Integer.parseInt(cards.getString(cards
                        .getColumnIndex("objectId")));

                card = Integer.parseInt(cards.getString(cards
                        .getColumnIndex("cardId")));

                String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                        + "/.Stampii/MediaCard/" + cardsId + ".png";
                ids.add(card);
                hm.put(cardsId, path);

                path = hm.get(cardsId);
                images.add(path);
            }
        }

        Button back = (Button) findViewById(R.id.back_button);
        back.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                finish();
            }
        });

        viewFlow = (ViewFlow) findViewById(R.id.viewflow);
        viewFlow.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this, images), position);

        ImageButton prevBtn = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.previous_button);
        prevBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                indexxx = viewFlow.getSelectedItemPosition() - 1;
                if (indexxx >= 0) {
                    viewFlow.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(Cards.this, images),
                            indexxx);
                    viewFlow.setSelectedItemPosition(indexxx);
                    Log.i("indexxx", "indexxx : " + indexxx);
                }
            }
        });

        ImageButton nextBtn = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.next_button);
        nextBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                indexxx = viewFlow.getSelectedItemPosition() + 1;
                if (indexxx < images.size()) {
                    viewFlow.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(Cards.this, images),
                            indexxx);
                    viewFlow.setSelectedItemPosition(indexxx);
                    Log.i("indexxx", "indexxx : " + indexxx);
                }
            }
        });

        Button info = (Button) findViewById(R.id.info_button);
        info.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Cards.this, SingleCardInfo.class);
                intent.putExtra("card_id",
                        ids.get(viewFlow.getSelectedItemPosition()));
                intent.putExtra("collection_id", collId);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        viewFlow.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }

    public String getOwnedCards(int sort, int collId, int extra) {
        String sql = "";
        switch (sort) {
        case 1: // Sort by Tags
            if (extra != 0)
                sql = "SELECT DISTINCT cm.cardId, cm.objectId "
                        + "FROM cardmedias AS cm " + "INNER JOIN cards AS cd "
                        + "ON (cm.cardId = cd.objectId) "
                        + "INNER JOIN cardtags AS ct "
                        + "ON (cd.objectId = ct.cardId) "
                        + "INNER JOIn tags AS tg "
                        + "ON (tg.objectId = ct.tagId) "
                        + "WHERE cd.collectionId=" + collId
                        + " AND cm.mediaType=" + mediaType
                        + " AND tg.objectId=" + extra;
            else if (extra == 0)
                sql = "SELECT DISTINCT cm.cardId, cm.objectId "
                        + "FROM cardmedias AS cm " + "INNER JOIN cards AS cd "
                        + "ON (cm.cardId = cd.objectId) "
                        + "INNER JOIN cardtags AS ct "
                        + "ON (cd.objectId = ct.cardId) "
                        + "INNER JOIn tags AS tg "
                        + "ON (tg.objectId = ct.tagId) "
                        + "WHERE cd.collectionId=" + collId
                        + " AND cm.mediaType=" + mediaType;
            break;
        case 2: // Sort by Categories
            if (extra != 0)
                sql = "SELECT DISTINCT cm.cardId, cm.objectId "
                    + "FROM cardmedias AS cm " + "INNER JOIN cards AS cd "
                    + "ON (cm.cardId = cd.objectId) "
                    + "INNER JOIN categories AS cats "
                    + "ON (cd.categoryId = cats.objectId) "
                    + "WHERE cd.collectionId=" + collId
                    + " AND cm.mediaType=" + mediaType
                    + " AND cats.objectId=" + extra;
            else if (extra == 0)
                sql = "SELECT DISTINCT cm.cardId, cm.objectId "
                    + "FROM cardmedias AS cm " + "INNER JOIN cards AS cd "
                    + "ON (cm.cardId = cd.objectId) "
                    + "INNER JOIN categories AS cats "
                    + "ON (cd.categoryId = cats.objectId) "
                    + "WHERE cd.collectionId=" + collId
                    + " AND cm.mediaType=" + mediaType;
            break;
        case 3: // Sort by Date
            String ASCDESC = getIntent().getStringExtra("ascdesc");
            if (extra != 0)
                sql = "SELECT DISTINCT cm.cardId, cm.objectId "
                    + "FROM cardmedias AS cm " + "INNER JOIN cards AS cd "
                    + "ON (cm.cardId = cd.objectId) "
                    + "INNER JOIN categories AS cats "
                    + "ON (cd.categoryId = cats.objectId) "
                    + "WHERE cd.collectionId=" + collId
                    + " AND cm.mediaType=" + mediaType
                    + " ORDER BY cd.dateCreated " + ASCDESC;
            else if (extra == 0)
                sql = "SELECT DISTINCT cm.cardId, cm.objectId "
                    + "FROM cardmedias AS cm " + "INNER JOIN cards AS cd "
                    + "ON (cm.cardId = cd.objectId) "
                    + "INNER JOIN categories AS cats "
                    + "ON (cd.categoryId = cats.objectId) "
                    + "WHERE cd.collectionId=" + collId
                    + " AND cm.mediaType=" + mediaType;
            break;
        }
        return sql;
    }

    public String getRepeatedCards(int sort, int collId, int extra){
        String sql="";
        switch (sort) {
        case 1: // Sort by Tags
            if (extra != 0)
                sql = "SELECT DISTINCT cm.cardId, cm.objectId "
                        + "FROM cardmedias AS cm " + "INNER JOIN cards AS cd "
                        + "ON (cm.cardId = cd.objectId) "
                        + "INNER JOIN cardtags AS ct "
                        + "ON (cd.objectId = ct.cardId) "
                        + "INNER JOIn tags AS tg "
                        + "ON (tg.objectId = ct.tagId) "
                        + "WHERE cd.collectionId=" + collId
                        + " AND cd.repeatsCount>1"
                        + " AND cm.mediaType=" + mediaType
                        + " AND tg.objectId=" + extra;
            else if (extra == 0)
                sql = "SELECT DISTINCT cm.cardId, cm.objectId "
                        + "FROM cardmedias AS cm " + "INNER JOIN cards AS cd "
                        + "ON (cm.cardId = cd.objectId) "
                        + "INNER JOIN cardtags AS ct "
                        + "ON (cd.objectId = ct.cardId) "
                        + "INNER JOIn tags AS tg "
                        + "ON (tg.objectId = ct.tagId) "
                        + "WHERE cd.collectionId=" + collId
                        + " AND cd.repeatsCount>1"
                        + " AND cm.mediaType=" + mediaType;
            break;
        case 2: // Sort by Categories
            if (extra != 0)
                sql = "SELECT DISTINCT cm.cardId, cm.objectId "
                    + "FROM cardmedias AS cm " + "INNER JOIN cards AS cd "
                    + "ON (cm.cardId = cd.objectId) "
                    + "INNER JOIN categories AS cats "
                    + "ON (cd.categoryId = cats.objectId) "
                    + "WHERE cd.collectionId=" + collId
                    + " AND cd.repeatsCount>1"
                    + " AND cm.mediaType=" + mediaType
                    + " AND cats.objectId=" + extra;
            else if (extra == 0)
                sql = "SELECT DISTINCT cm.cardId, cm.objectId "
                    + "FROM cardmedias AS cm " + "INNER JOIN cards AS cd "
                    + "ON (cm.cardId = cd.objectId) "
                    + "INNER JOIN categories AS cats "
                    + "ON (cd.categoryId = cats.objectId) "
                    + "WHERE cd.collectionId=" + collId
                    + " AND cd.repeatsCount>1"
                    + " AND cm.mediaType=" + mediaType;
            break;
        case 3: // Sort by Date
            String ASCDESC = getIntent().getStringExtra("ascdesc");
            Log.d("","ASCDESC : "+ASCDESC);
            if (extra != 0)
                sql = "SELECT DISTINCT cm.cardId, cm.objectId "
                    + "FROM cardmedias AS cm " + "INNER JOIN cards AS cd "
                    + "ON (cm.cardId = cd.objectId) "
                    + "INNER JOIN categories AS cats "
                    + "ON (cd.categoryId = cats.objectId) "
                    + "WHERE cd.collectionId=" + collId
                    + " AND cd.repeatsCount>1"
                    + " AND cm.mediaType=" + mediaType
                    + " ORDER BY cd.dateCreated " + ASCDESC;
            else if (extra == 0)
                sql = "SELECT DISTINCT cm.cardId, cm.objectId "
                    + "FROM cardmedias AS cm " + "INNER JOIN cards AS cd "
                    + "ON (cm.cardId = cd.objectId) "
                    + "INNER JOIN categories AS cats "
                    + "ON (cd.categoryId = cats.objectId) "
                    + "WHERE cd.collectionId=" + collId
                    + " AND cd.repeatsCount>1"
                    + " AND cm.mediaType=" + mediaType;
            break;
        }
        return sql;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you are quite close to getting it work.

`getCount()` should be like this:

```
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return ids.size();
}
```

**EDITED**:
You should create only one instance of `ImageAdapter`, you are creating new instances inside `onClick`. Also you should use `setSelection()` instead of `setSelectedItemPosition()`. It seems The latter is intended for internal:

```
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            indexxx = viewFlow.getSelectedItemPosition()-1;
            if (indexxx>=0) {
                viewFlow.setSelection(indexxx);
                Log.i("indexxx", "indexxx : " + indexxx);
            }
        }
        /* ... */
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            indexxx = viewFlow.getSelectedItemPosition()+1;
            if (indexxx<images.size()) { // Should be <, you have a wrong boundary check here!!!
                viewFlow.setSelection(indexxx);
                Log.i("indexxx", "indexxx : " + indexxx);
            }
        }
```

Comment: actually that should work, but do you have any idea how can I add only 3 bitmaps on every swipe. The current, the previous and the next.Because if i try to load all bitmaps I'm getting out of memory exception. Thanks !

Comment: I think you should use thumbnails instead of original images.

Comment: I think it's too complicated actually, but that's the way my boss want that listing to work.

Comment: You adjust the number of views (or bitmaps in your case) loaded by setting the side buffer of the view flow. What is your current side buffer value? It's typically set in your layout xml. It defaults to 2 which means 2 * 2 + 1 = 5 loaded bitmaps. If your bitmaps are really large you might run out of memory.